# How to use array_filter in loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, array-filter

I want to filter the data from the array in a loop. All i want to know is can I use the array_filter inside loop because i am using it and it is not working properly
This is the array which i am getting from DB

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Chocolate Manufacturers,C
        [1] => ,,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers
        [2] => 
    )
```

I am making the array unique by using this code

```
$num = 2;
for($i=0;$i<count($listing);$i++){

    //echo var_export($listing[$i]->cat_title).'<br>';
    $listing_cat[$i] = rtrim(ltrim($listing[$i]->cat_title,','),',');
    $listing_cat[$i] = explode(',', $listing_cat[$i]);
    //$listing_cat[$i] = array_filter(array_keys($listing_cat[$i]), function ($k){ return strlen($k)>=3; });
    $listing_cat[$i] = array_filter($listing_cat[$i], function ($sentence){
        //divide the each sentence in words
        $words = explode(',',$sentence);
        $resSentence = [];
        //check each words if their length is more then $num
        foreach($words as $word){
            if(strlen($word) > $num){
                $resSentence[] = $word;
            }
        }
        return implode(' ', $resSentence);
    });
    $listing_cat[$i] = array_unique($listing_cat[$i]);

    $listing_cat[$i] = implode(',', $listing_cat[$i]);
    $listing_cat[$i] = rtrim(ltrim($listing_cat[$i],','),',');
    //$tags['title'][$i] = rtrim(ltrim($listing[$i]->cat_title,','),',');
}
```

After running this code result is showing like this

```
   Array (
    [0] => Chocolate Manufacturers,C
    [1] => Chocolate Manufacturers
    [2] => 
   )
```

But what i want is to remove the C from the first array i mean to say the unwanted string or string which length will be less than 2 i want to remove that.

**Expected Result:**

```
Array (
        [0] => Chocolate Manufacturers
        [1] => Chocolate Manufacturers
        [2] => 
       )
```

i used the below function to remove

```
$NUM = 2;
$listings[$i] = array_filter($listings[$i], function ($element){ 
        return ($element[$i] > $NUM);
        });
```

But i think because it is in loop it is not working properly. I am placing this code above the `array_unique` line in loop. All i want is to remove the value which length will be less than 2.

**Finally i have achieved my desired answer**

```
    $num = 2;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($listing); $i++) {
    //$listing_cat[$i] = array_unique($listing[$i]->cat_title);
    $listing_cat[$i] = rtrim(ltrim($listing[$i]->cat_title, ','), ',');

    $sentence = $listing_cat[$i];

    //divide the each sentence in words
    $words = explode(',', $sentence);
    $resSentence = [];

    //check each words if their length is more then $num
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (strlen($word) > $num) {
            $resSentence[] = $word;
        }
    }
    $listing_cat[$i] = array_unique($resSentence);

    $listing_cat[$i] = implode(',',$listing_cat[$i]);

    $listing_cat[$i] = rtrim(ltrim($listing_cat[$i],','),',');
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($listing_cat);
echo '</pre>';
```

it is showing perfect result what i want

```
Array (
        [0] => Chocolate Manufacturers
        [1] => Chocolate Manufacturers
        [2] => 
       )
```

Thanks all for help really appriciated

Comment: I assume the final output you want is:

`Array (
    [0] => Chocolate Manufacturers
)`

Right?

Comment: yes right this is what i want

Comment: I want to remove all the text which string length will be less than 2

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I recommend you not to use `$listing` along with `$listings` as variable names as it can easily lead to confusion and is not a good readability (especially confusing here on StackOverflow).

Then: You have an error in your code. You are not checking for the length (count) but for the string itself which does resolve in TRUE.

You have:

```
$NUM = 2;

$listings[$i] = array_filter($listings[$i], function ($element){ 
    return ($element[$i] > $NUM);
    }
);
```

You should have:

```
$NUM = 2;

$listings[$i] = array_filter($listings[$i], function ($element) use ($NUM) { 
    return (strlen($element[$i]) >= $NUM);
    }
);
```

Comment: I'll provide a Fiddle in a moment.

Comment: @androidavid : " _i mean to say the unwanted string or string which length will be less than 2 i want to remove that_", this was needed so I think `return (strlen($element[$i]) > $NUM);` will be `return (strlen($element[$i]) >= $NUM);`

Comment: But it is not removing the `C` from the array

Comment: @NewbieJavaDeveloper You are right. But still the 'C' should be removed in my unedited post which the author says it does still appear so it does not solve the problem itself. But thanks :)

Comment: @jayantrawat Can you provide more information? I was trying to reproduce your code but there is a lot missing. I do not know where cat_title etc. comes from. Can you provide a working version of your code with a sample array so that I can provide you a solution?

Comment: Actually in `$listing`  variable i am saving all the data as array from db . The data is too big so i can't provide you here. And the cat_title is the field in database which is holding the category title. and to print the cat_title from db i am using loop and the first result of array above  is coming when i am printing that cat_title

Comment: okay i explain you the whole process i have a user which has three listings and all listing are lying on different categories the first is the example of that listing

Comment: The first business categories are `Chocolate Manufacturers,C` and the second business categories are `,,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers`

Comment: @jayantrawat but you could easily provide a small extract of that. For example you could remove all attributes that are not required for this question and limit the array to 4 or 5 entries and then provide an example here.

Comment: @jayantrawat Please take a look at my post edit based on Yoshi's response.

Comment: As @Yoshi said i used it too before with this the result is coming blank

Comment: and as per your suggestion i also changed the variable name to $listing_cat

Comment: So you are saying that use($NUM) behind the function has no effect?

Comment: Yes instead it is not showing the result. before it was showing result atleast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129536/discussion-between-jayant-rawat-and-androidavid).

Answer (score 0):

As you are code say, `$listings` is contains sentence. If I got your problem properly then, you want to remove smaller from each sentences of the `$listings` variable. 
You can replace your this code:

```
$NUM = 2;
$listings[$i] = array_filter($listings[$i], function ($element){ 
    return ($element[$i] > $NUM);
});
```

with the following codeblock:

```
   $num = 2;
   $sentence = $listings[$i];
   //divide the each sentence in words
   $words = explode(',',$sentence);
   $resSentence = [];
   //check each words if their length is more then $num
   foreach($words as $word){
       if(strlen($word) > $num){
           $resSentence[] = $word;
       }
   }
   $listings[$i] = implode(' ', $resSentence);
```

**Update**
I have check out this program below, is it the whole think what you want?

```
<?php
$listing_cat = ['Chocolate Manufacturers,C', ',,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers', ''];
$num = 2;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($listing_cat); $i++) {

    $listing_cat[$i] = rtrim(ltrim($listing_cat[$i], ','), ',');
    $sentence = $listing_cat[$i];

    //divide the each sentence in words
    $words = explode(',', $sentence);
    $resSentence = [];

    //check each words if their length is more then $num
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (strlen($word) > $num) {
            $resSentence[] = $word;
        }
    }
    $listing_cat[$i] = implode($resSentence);
}
var_dump($listing_cat);
```

Comment: Where i do place this code in loop or outside the loop and one more thing should i have to replace this code with my old code or have to add this with my code

Comment: 1. you need to use use($num) to give the num into the functions and 2. You are just spitting 'Chocolate Manufacturers' into 'Chocolate' and 'Manufacturers' and check their length. How does this help? I am curious :)

Comment: Ops, there is no space in between `,` and `C`!! let me modify my code.

Comment: My problem is still the same it is not removing the C

Comment: This is the result of your code. It is also returning C

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chocolate Manufacturers
            [1] => C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chocolate Manufacturers
            [2] => Chocolate Manufacturers
            [4] => Chocolate Manufacturers
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

)`

Comment: Updated the answer, can you try now?

Comment: Nope not working and you forget to place semicolon after $sentence variable

Comment: Can you tell me the output now?

Comment: I've commented out right below the question. Check it out. That's the final output he wants.

Comment: This is the result `Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)`

Comment: I have attached updated code the answer, checkout if this is all you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have updated your code a bit and it works for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Then I am expecting the answer to be approved and upvoted by you. best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code:

```
function arr_filter($arr, $min_length) {
    define('STR_MIN_LEN', $min_length);
    $arr = array_filter($arr);
    $arr_explode = [];

    foreach($arr as $value) {
        $arr_explode = explode(',', $value);
        $arr_explode = array_unique(array_filter($arr_explode));
        $arr_explode = array_filter($arr_explode, function($element) {
            return strlen($element) >= STR_MIN_LEN;
        });
    }

    return array_values(array_unique($arr_explode));
}

var_dump(arr_filter($arr, 2));
```

The above code is written as per your requirements. You could try it out and see if it works. This code may not be flexible. You can check it out with various test cases. Hope it works.

**EDIT**

I assume you have a multidimensional array like:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'Chocolate Manufacturers,C',
        ',,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers',
        ''
    ),
    array(
        'Ice Cream Manufacturers,C',
        ',,,Ice Cream Manufacturers,,Ice Cream Manufacturers,,Ice Cream Manufacturers',
        ''
    )
);
```

and the code is:

```
function arr_filter($arr, $min_length) {
    define('STR_MIN_LEN', $min_length);
    $final_arr = array();

    foreach($arr as $value) {
        $value = array_filter($value);
        $arr_explode = [];

        foreach($value as $another_value) {
            $arr_explode = explode(',', $another_value);
            $arr_explode = array_unique(array_filter($arr_explode));
            $arr_explode = array_filter($arr_explode, function($element) {
                return strlen($element) >= STR_MIN_LEN;
            });
        }

        $final_arr[] = array_values(array_unique($arr_explode));
    }

    return $final_arr;
}

var_dump(arr_filter($arr, 2));
```

I've added this code to make it work with multidimensional array. Hope it works for sure.

**EDIT 2**

```
function arr_filter($arr, $min_length) {
    define('STR_MIN_LEN', $min_length);
    $final_arr = array();

    foreach($arr as $value) {
        $value = array_filter($value);
        $arr_explode_final = [];

        foreach($value as $another_value) {
            $arr_explode = explode(',', $another_value);
            $arr_explode = array_filter($arr_explode, function($element) {
                return strlen($element) >= STR_MIN_LEN;
            });

            // the comma will be added if the string has two different words with comma-separated like `Chocolate Manufacturers, Ice Cream Manufacturers` else comma will be ommited
            $arr_explode_final[] = implode(',', array_unique($arr_explode)); 
        }

        $final_arr[] = $arr_explode_final;
    }
    return $final_arr;
}

var_dump(arr_filter($arr, 2));
```

Comment: It works, But it remove the whole data from first array instead of removing the `C` only

Comment: Mention me what your final output with this code was and also the output you expect.

Comment: Here is the final output

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chocolate Manufacturers
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

)`

Comment: The array you mentioned in the code was part of a multidimensional array?

Comment: I am sorry actually i have multiple index in one array

Comment: You can see on my question the first array is how i am getting my raw array

Comment: Like the one you mentioned in the question, the expected result?